# not getting desired output with cut command?

Tags: cut, filter

```
[root@localhost ~]#  ps aux | grep ata
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:52   0:00 [ata/0]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:52   0:00 [ata_aux]
root      1655  0.0  2.6  22144 13556 tty1     Ss+  07:53   0:18 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-t1gMCU/database -nolisten tcp vt1
root      3180  0.0  0.1   4312   728 pts/0    S+   14:09   0:00 grep ata
[root@localhost ~]#  ps aux | grep ata | cut -d" " -f 2

[root@localhost ~]#
```

I would expect second column in the output; but not getting anything. Any ideas ?

Comment: [Here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142735/linux-cut-help-how-to-specify-more-spaces-for-the-delimiter)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-several-sequential-delimiters-as-one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `-d " "`, the field separator is one (and only one) space character. Contrary to the shell word splitting, `cut` doesn't treat space any different than any other character. So `cut -d " " -f2` returns `""` in `root   19`, just like it would return `""` for `cut -d: -f2` in `root:::19`.

You'd need to either squeeze the blanks to transform any sequence of space into **one** space:

```
ps aux | grep ata | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Or use `awk` where in its default spitting mode, it doesn't use a separator but splits into the list of sequences of non-blank characters:

```
ps aux | awk '/ata/{print $2}'
```

In this case though, you may want to use:

```
pgrep -f ata
```

Or at least:

```
ps -eo pid= -o args= | awk '/ata/{print $1}'
```

To match against the arguments only.

Comment: Would be convenient for `cut` to have a wildcard space argument... ( I.E. cut -d '\s*' )

Comment: @EddieB, you use `tr` for that `tr -s '[[:space:]]' '[\t*]' | cut  ...` or use `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
ps aux | awk '/ata/{print $2}'
```

The `cut` command you are using is not giving the desired output as there are more than one space between columns.

Comment: FWIW, fields being separated by a variable amount of whitespace is one of the few cases where awk beats cut for regular field extraction. Cut is more useful in the general case but it doesn't handle multi-character delimiters (esp variable-length ones) very well at all.

Comment: @JoelDavis, GNU or busybox `cut` may not handle multibyte character delimiters but other like heirloom toolchest's or ksh93 builtin ones do. Similarly some `awk` implementations like `mawk` don't support multibyte characters very well (try `mawk -F'[áóíúýé]' '{print $2}'` for instance)